# Why can't I purrr:: map this list without anonymous function (sapply works)

Tags: r, sapply, purrr

I recently tried to use `map_dbl` in some code where `sapply` had worked nicely, and stumbled over the inconsistency below. What's wrong?

```
library(nlme)
fm1 = nlsList(uptake ~ SSasympOff(conc, Asym, lrc, c0),
               data = CO2, start = c(Asym = 30, lrc = -4.5, c0 = 52))
# Ok
deviance = sapply(fm1, function(x) deviance(x))
deviance = sapply(fm1, deviance)
deviance = purrr::map_dbl(fm1, function(x) deviance(x))

# fails
deviance = purrr::map_dbl(fm1, deviance)
# Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
str(deviance(fm1[[1]]))
# num 11.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`purrr` doesn't interpret `deviance` as function as you have a function `deviance` and a variable (in the global env) named `deviance`

`purrr` internally uses `as_function` on the second argument. So in your case:

```
deviance = sapply(fm1, deviance)
class(deviance) # "numeric"
```

In this sense `deviance` is interpreted as a numerical vector. From `?map`

> If character or integer vector, e.g. "y", it is converted to an
>   extractor function, function(x) x[["y"]]. To index deeply into a
>   nested list, use multiple values; c("x", "y") is equivalent to
>   z[["x"]][["y"]]. You can also set .null to set a default to use
>   instead of NULL for absent components.

The following works:

```
rm(deviance)
my_deviance = purrr::map_dbl(fm1, deviance)
```

as does:

```
purrr::map_dbl(fm1, ~deviance(.x))
```

and:

```
deviance = sapply(fm1, deviance)
map_dbl(fm1, stats::deviance)
```

and (as @Axeman mendions in the comments)

```
purrr::map_dbl(fm1, match.fun(deviance))
```

Comment: Or `purrr::map_dbl(fm1, match.fun(deviance))`.

Comment: Sh... I just noted that is my own bad coding practice, not nlme's. Pardon my stupidity.